# Mysql: Create inline table within select statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way in MySql to create an inline table to use for join?

Something like:

```
SELECT LONG [1,2,3] as ID, VARCHAR(1) ['a','b','c'] as CONTENT
```

that would output

```
|  ID  |  CONTENT  |
| LONG | VARCHAR(1)|
+------+-----------+
|   1  |    'a'    |
|   2  |    'b'    |
|   3  |    'c'    |
```

and that I could use in a join like this:

```
SELECT 
  MyTable.*,
  MyInlineTable.CONTENT
FROM
  MyTable
  JOIN 
    (SELECT LONG [1,2,3] as ID, VARCHAR(1) ['a','b','c'] as CONTENT MyInlineTable)
  ON MyTable.ID = MyInlineTable.ID
```

I realize that I can do

```
SELECT 1,'a' UNION SELECT 2,'b' UNION SELECT 3,'c'
```

But that seems pretty evil

I don't want to do a stored procedure because potentially a,b,c can change at every query and the size of the data as well. Also a stored procedure needs to be saved in the database, and I don't want to have to modify the database just for that.
View is the same thing.

What I am really looking for is something that does `SELECT 1,'a' UNION SELECT 2,'b' UNION SELECT 3,'c'` with a nicer syntax.

Comment: Seems like a straightforward concept with obvious use cases. I need to find something like this too.

Comment: Have you found any solution? I'm curious

Comment: @FernandoCarvalhosa: nope, it looks like it can't be done without union

Comment: @d--b Got nothing with a temp table? By the way, why does it looks so bad to you to use union? Performance issues?

Comment: Updated my answer with some code with temp table. Didn't test it, will do it tonight

Comment: Just tested it and it worked. Way easier to add data then using `UNION`. The temp table will be deleted after you close the connection. Recommend you to take a look at it when you have time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *What I am really looking for is something that does SELECT 1,'a' UNION SELECT 2,'b' UNION SELECT 3,'c' with a nicer syntax.*

Yes, it is possible with **[ROW CONSTRUCTOR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html)** introduced in MySQL 8.0.19:

```
VALUES ROW (1,'a'), ROW(2,'b'), ROW(3,'c')
```

and with JOIN:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab 
JOIN (VALUES ROW (1,'a'), ROW(2,'b'), ROW(3,'c') ) sub(id, content)
  ON tab.id = sub.id;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5a603340c5b91d85f097f9e49db25f69)**

Comment: Except the first column is not named `id`. "The columns of the table output from VALUES have the implicitly named columns column_0, column_1, column_2, and so on, always beginning with 0."

Comment: @BillKarwin you can name the columns what ever you want:`SELECT * FROM (VALUES ROW(1, 'a'), ROW(2, 'b')) foo(foo_id, foo_content);`

Comment: @Jalal, Thank you, that was not clear to me in the documentation.

Answer (score 8):

The only ways i can remember now is using `UNION` or creating a `TEMPORARY TABLE` and inserting those values into it. Does it suit you?

---

`TEMPORARY_TABLE` (tested and it works):

**Creation:**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE MyInlineTable (id LONG, content VARCHAR(1) );

INSERT INTO MyInlineTable VALUES
(1, 'a'),
(2, 'b'),
(3, 'c');
```

**Usage:**

```
SELECT 
  MyTable.*,
  MyInlineTable.CONTENT
FROM
  MyTable
  JOIN 
    SELECT * FROM MyInlineTable;
  ON MyTable.ID = MyInlineTable.ID
```

---

`TEMPORARY_TABLES` **lifetime** [(reference)](http://bisqlserver2005.blogspot.com.br/2008/09/what-is-life-time-of-temporary-table-on.html):

> Temporary tables are automatically dropped when they go out of scope, unless they have already been explicitly dropped using DROP TABLE:

.

> All other local temporary tables are dropped automatically at the end of the current session.

.

> Global temporary tables are automatically dropped when the session that created the table ends and all other tasks have stopped referencing them. The association between a task and a table is maintained only for the life of a single Transact-SQL statement. This means that a global temporary table is dropped at the completion of the last Transact-SQL statement that was actively referencing the table when the creating session ended.`

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Do with [**stored procedures**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) or [**views**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html).

Comment: That seems like a way too heavy solution to me... (see edits in the question)