# IFNULL with IN statement with mysql

Tags: mysql

I am Newbie to mysql....it may look dump question....but i have been trying this from 3 hours...here what i am trying to do....

```
SELECT
  MERCHANT_ID,
  IFNULL(COUNT(SUBSCRIBE_ID),0)
FROM SUBSCRIBE_TABLE
WHERE
  MERCHANT_ID IS NULL OR 
  MERCHANT_ID IN(1000000000066,1000000000104,1000000000103,1000000000105)
GROUP BY MERCHANT_ID
ORDER BY
  FIND_IN_SET(MERCHANT_ID,'1000000000066,1000000000104,1000000000103,1000000000105');
```

AND the output is...

```
+------------------+---------------------------------+
| MERCHANT_ID      |   IFNULL(COUNT(SUBSCRIBE_ID),0) |
+------------------+---------------------------------+
|    1000000000066 |                               2 |
|    1000000000103 |                               1 |
+------------------+---------------------------------+
```

but i am expecting in following manner...

```
+------------------+---------------------------------+
| MERCHANT_ID      |   IFNULL(COUNT(SUBSCRIBE_ID),0) |
+------------------+---------------------------------+
|    1000000000066 |                               2 |
|    1000000000104 |                               0 |
|    1000000000103 |                               1 |
|    1000000000105 |                               0 |
+------------------+---------------------------------+
```

i tried adding `MERCHANT_ID IS NULL`... but not able get the result with default value... :(

Answer (score 1):

You will only get records that are actually in `SUBSCRIBE_TABLE`. If you want to get records for all your ids, you have to "create a temporary table" (or use a subquery with `UNION` in thise case) with those values first, and then join your results to it.

Your query could look like this:

```
SELECT
  merchant_id,
  COUNT(subscribe_id)
FROM
  (SELECT 1000000000066 AS merchant_id, 1 AS SortKey
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 1000000000104 AS merchant_id, 2 AS SortKey
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 1000000000103 AS merchant_id, 3 AS SortKey
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 1000000000105 AS merchant_id, 4 AS SortKey
  ) AS temp
LEFT JOIN subscribe_table USING (merchant_id)
GROUP BY merchant_id
ORDER BY SortKey ASC
```

I replaced your `FIND_IN_SET` with the column `SortKey` in the subquery. `COUNT` will only count non-null rows and will return 0 if none are found. You don't need the `IFNULL` around it.

If you have more than those 4 `merchant_id`s you might want to look into doing the same thing with a temporary table. See here for examples:
[Mysql: Create inline table within select statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520442/mysql-create-inline-table-within-select-statement)