# How to define a table of inline values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Here is a way of defining *inline* table data within a SQL query:

```
SELECT 1 `id`, 'hello' `name`
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 `id`, 'goodbye' `name`
```

You can put this into something that expects a query returning the columns `id, name` and it will work correctly. However, this takes up a lot of unnecessary characters when there are more than one or two rows.

**Is there a better way than UNION'ing multiple SELECT's for defining an inline table of values within a MySQL query?**

Comment: You could create a temporary table. Here's a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520442/mysql-create-inline-table-within-select-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a sequence of integers and you're using [MariaDB, the MySQL fork](https://mariadb.com/), you can use the [SEQUENCE storage engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sequence/).

```
SELECT seq FROM seq_0_to_6
```

for example, will give you a table of integers 0-6.

Other than that, you asked whether there's a more efficient way than a `UNION ALL` query or a temp table definition to get a so-called inline table.

The answer is **no, not really.**

But there's one minor efficiency you didn't pick up on.  You don't need to repeat the column names more than once in your `UNION ALL` cascade.  So, instead of

```
SELECT 1 id, 'hello' name
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 id, 'goodbye' name
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 id, 'salut' name
```

You can do this:

```
SELECT 1 id, 'hello' name
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'goodbye'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'salut'
```

It saves a few characters.

Notice also that `UNION ALL` is a better choice than `UNION` because `UNION` implies the removal of duplicates, which in turn implies a bunch of processing. `UNION ALL` skips that.